# Infinite loop error python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am coding a simple chatbot for my computers class and I have run into a problem. I am trying to create a function that will ask for someone's name and then reply saying "Nice to meet you" and then their name. My function keep repeating "Hi Ii'm Bob. Whats your name?" over and over again. It works when its outside of the function but i cant figure out why it wont work when inside.

```
def hello():
    while True:
        print("Hi I'm Bob! What's your name?")
    name = input("Name:")
    print("Nice to meet you "+(name))
```

Comment: Your input statement is outside the loop, so it never gets executed. Your indentation is all wrong.

Comment: What did you think `while True:` did?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should simply indent the question and answer into the loop:

```
def hello():
    while True:
        print("Hi I'm Bob! What's your name?")
        name = input("Name:")
        print("Nice to meet you "+(name))
```

Answer (score 0):

The while loop will always be true, so it never gets to your input - you need to indent the name/print to be within the while loop.

```
def hello():
    while True:
        print("Hi I'm Bob! What's your name?")
        name = input("Name:")
        print("Nice to meet you "+(name))
```

Comment: Ah, derp - I thought he wanted it to keep asking, hence the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
def hello():
    while True:
        print("Hi I'm Bob! What's your name?")
        name = input("Name:")
        print("Nice to meet you " + name)
```